# Basic contact form php not working, getting empty messages from my form

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My contact form sends blank body_messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859615/my-contact-form-sends-blank-body-messages)

My contact form is sending emails but they are all empty. All I get is this;

```
From:
Email:
Company:
```

I really need this working.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="contact_form" action="kontakt.php" method="post">
<p><input type="text" required="required" id="name" name="name" class="text_input" size="22"  />
<label for="name">Namn *</label></p>

<p><input type="text" required="required" id="company" name="company" class="text_input" size="22"  />
<label for="company">Företag *</label></p>

<p><input type="email" required="required" id="email" name="email" class="text_input"  size="22"  />
<label for="email">Epost *</label></p>

<p><textarea required="required" name="content" class="textarea" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>

<p><button type="submit" class="button white"><span>Skicka</span></button></p>
<input type="hidden" value="info@web.se" name="contact_to"/>
</form>
```

and this is my php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$content = $_POST['content'];
$mail_to = 'info@web.se';
$subject = 'Lilla form'.$name;
$body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$content;
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Check if your <form> tag is having POST or GET as the method? In fact I think you should update your code and add the <form> tag in it so that we can better figure out what is going wrong

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST);` as first debugging step.

Comment: I have the tags they just did not show up, can u see now?

Comment: What does `ini_get('variables_order')` tell you?

Comment: What are you doing with $mail_status? just use the mail() command.

Comment: where do I place var_dump($_POST);?

Comment: @nickhar He did just use the mail() command and is capturing the return value -- or whether the mail() command succeeded or not.

Comment: How is `Company:` showing up in your email when it doesn't exist in the code?

Comment: There is no closing tag for the form (`</form>`) in the code you posted. Does your source contain one?

Comment: ini_get('variables_order') does not say much jack, Im new at this

Comment: @GeorgeReith - it was in there. The OP just mis-formatted.

Comment: sorry not company, its says message, my source have a </form>